# What is the "Anchor number"?

Tags: android, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I don't know where "Anchor number" is.

I want to share my Android Anchor with HoloLens.
Anchor number is required when sharing with Android.
Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: You will get the Anchor ID from Azure Spatial Anchors(ASA) after you successfully save the Anchor. (The Anchor Identifier is returned to you in the completion block.)

If you want to share these Anchor Identifiers across users or devices you need to [create a service to store these IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-use-cosmos-db-to-store-anchors#deploy-the-sharing-anchors-service). Devices can then just request the persisted IDs to this service you created.

Once the device has the IDs then it can be passed to the ASA service to search for the anchors in the current space (also have to provide the current space with the spatial information captured by the device).

In this screenshot you can see some code illustrating how to save the Anchor in ASA:

[image: A frame from the Channel 9 video "Developing Mobile Augmented Reality (AR) Applications with Azure Spatial Anchors" showing code to use the demo Sharing Service.]

(Source Channel 9 session [Developing Mobile Augmented Reality (AR) Applications with Azure Spatial Anchors](https://youtu.be/CVmfP8TaqNU?t=2486))